# Curl call from C#

Tags: c#, curl

I have to make a simple curl call from C# to an api.
curl https://payxxx.xx/post_api
-d "apikey=YOUR_API_KEY"
-d "command=create_pay"
-d "params={"amount":2569,"description":"A new Pay"}"
I need to save the response.
I have see samples with httpclient but can't make it work.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

       
        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "apikey=xxxxxxx"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "command=create_pay"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "params={\\'amount\\':2569,\\'description\\':\\'A new Pay\\',\\'pay_methods\\':\\'\\'}"),
        });


        
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://payxxx.xx/post_api", requestContent);

       
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

       
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
           
            MessageBox.Show(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        }
```

I get always wrong api_key,(it's correct one) I think i'm not sending the correct call.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "can't make it work" - what symtpoms do you experience? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Try to take Fiddler or some other debugging proxy and just compare requests (url, query, headers, etc. ) from curl and from your code. And then fix your code to remove differences between requsts.